# Tablesorter resizable with reorder not working together

Tags: tablesorter, resizable

I have trouble in using Tablesorter resizable with reorder, I can’t resize when reorder widget is active, when I resize it moves instead. Is there any workaround to resize without affecting the reorder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The reorder widget is still in alpha development and does not properly work with the resizable widget; it needs a lot of work to be production ready.

I just now tried to combine the resizable widget with the [dragtable jQuery UI widget](http://akottr.github.io/dragtable/) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/4954/)), but it appears the dragtable code needs a bit of tweaking to make both widgets work together.

```
$(function () {
    var $table = $('table')
        .dragtable({
            dragHandle: '.table-handle',
            persistState: function (table) {
                // remove div wrapper, or swapped header
                // contents will be replaced
                $table.find('thead .tablesorter-header-inner').contents().unwrap();
                $table.trigger('updateAll', false);
            }
        })
        .tablesorter({
            theme: 'blue',
            selectorSort: '.sort',
            widgets: ['resizable']
        });
});
```